# Capture images and store them only inside apk in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, assets

i want to use the device camera and capture image  , than convert it to lower quality image and store that image inside "assets" instead inside the cellphone .

i am not expecting to the full code , but the idea in general would be great .

the main issue is how to get the picture from taking picture to assets so i can use it .

thanks !

Comment: this is not possible,because,when you make .APK ,its a decoded/binary file.You can't inject any thing inside it.

Comment: above comment is copied from my below answer.

Comment: so what is the best solution to store pictures that related only to this app ? can you give me direction so i will study it

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that... After apk is build, you can't insert anything inside it at run time.
You can only save data on either internal memory or external memory but **not inside apk(through any mechanism)**

Comment: thank you ,how can i capture images and store them for my app uses in private folder?